# Kmeans - Why is .cluster_centres_ returning no attributes

Tags: python, k-means

Any idea why .cluster_centres_ in below code is returning no attributes ? The data frame is formatted and consists of scaled information. It looks like on screen below

[data.DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYVn5.png)

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

def pd_centers(featuresUsed, centers):
    from itertools import cycle, islice
    from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    colNames = list(featuresUsed)
    colNames.append('prediction')

    # Zip with a column called 'prediction' (index)
    Z = [np.append(A, index) for index, A in enumerate(centers)]

    # Convert to pandas for plotting
    P = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=colNames)
    P['prediction'] = P['prediction'].astype(int)
    return P

path = "C:\PYTHON\PYTHON FOR DATA SCIENCE\Week-1-Intro-new\Week-1-Intro-new\database.sqlite"

cnx = sqlite3.connect(path)
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Player_Attributes",cnx)
df = df.dropna()

select5features = ['gk_kicking', 'potential', 'marking', 'interceptions', 'standing_tackle']

df_select = df[select5features].copy(deep=True)

data = scale(df_select)
nClusters = 4
model = KMeans(init='k-means++',n_clusters=4, n_init=20).fit(data)

pd.value_counts(model.labels_, sort=False)

P = pd_centers(featuresUsed=select5features, centers=model.cluster_centres_)
```

P value to create plot using function

Comment: Please provide the exact output you are currently getting and the ideal output/behavior you would like to see. This will help others to track down the exact problem.

Comment: The output was supposed to be 4 clusters of correlation between five player attributes. as per the code above. It would be stored in variable P and later used to generate a graph. Everything seems to work up until P = pd_centers(featuresUsed=select5features, centers=model.cluster_centres_) with cluster_centreS_ returning no attributes